# How to parse this JSON response

Tags: android, json

I am using JSon response to parse title,date content and thumbnail images and place that in listview. I parsed title, date,content and name which are obtaining in listview but when i included thumbnail images json parsing in loop to display in listview nothing is displaying in output.Can any one help me how to parse json response. JSON responseis here

```
//json response to parse  
{
 "status": "ok",

"posts": [
    {
        "id": 2498,
        "title": "jigsaw lamp imported from thailand",
        "content": "<p>Hi. It&#8217;s a invitation to have a look at a unique lamp shade called jigsaw lamp from thailand. Available in multi attractive colours.</p>\n",
        "date": "2012-12-26 09:48:15",
         "author": {
            "name": "Tapas123456",
                        },
            "attachments": [
            {
                "description": "",
                "caption": "",
                "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
                "images": {

                    "thumbnail": {
                        "url": "http://site/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/646675-50x47.jpg",

                    }
                }
            },...............
```

following code is used to add images and data to listview

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
JSONArray posts = null;

// All static variables
static final String URL = "website/ads/?json=get_recent_posts";



  static final String KEY_POSTS = "posts";
  static final String KEY_ID = "id";
  static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
  static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
  static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
  static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
  static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
  static final String KEY_ATTACHMENTS = "attachments";
  static final String KEY_SLUG = "slug";
  static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
  static final String KEY_IMAGES = "images";
  static final String KEY_URL = "url";

 ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
            try {
        JSONArray posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);
        JSONArray attachments = json.getJSONArray(KEY_ATTACHMENTS);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
            for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);

                //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                //loop                  
                for(int j = 0; j < attachments.length(); j++){
                    JSONObject d = attachments.getJSONObject(j);
                    String slug = c.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                    JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                    JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                    String url = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, id);
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
        map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug);
        map.put(KEY_URL, url);


        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
            }   }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


        }
    });     
}   
     }
```

Comment: Answers will be accepted i did not get proper answer for my previous question

Comment: I doubt all of the answers you received were wrong : http://stackoverflow.com/users/1784844/arun-a?tab=questions&sort=votes

Comment: not wrong answer dude i used your answer but it did not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **attachement** is inside post array in **json** but in code you kept it outside for loop for posts. Please keep it inside to get each attachment per post.

Try applying as per the following image and cross verify the implementataions.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: your json format is wrong.`"url": "http://site/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/646675-50x47.jpg",` remove the comma just after url.

Comment: medium small images url's are there next to that so i edited those things

Comment: try giving proper json structures when ever asking for a solution. Its really a pain answering for a incomplete/vague questions.